# How to run windows IOT core Console Visual C++ Application in Windows 10 IOT device.?

Tags: windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10

I am able to execute it via power shell . But not able to directly run from IOT Device raspberry pi.
If there is not  available option for execute Console Application from IOT device which is best alternative application platform for this?
IS there any tools availables that convert Console application to Application that can be run on IOT device ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to directly run the console application when you are in develop,
You can refer to this [link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/memorystatus) to get the steps of running and debugging C++ console application on Windows IoT Core device.
If you use visual Studio to develop your application, you can install [Windows IoT Core Project Templates for VS 2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MicrosoftIoT.WindowsIoTCoreProjectTemplatesforVS15) and then build a background application. [Background Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/backgroundapplications) are applications that have no direct UI(Headless). Once deployed and configured, these applications launch at machine startup and run continuously without any process lifetime management resource use limitations. Hope that can help you.

Answer (score 0):

it's easiest to view console output from a visual c++ app if you launch the app from an ssh session. try using putty to connect to your raspberry pi, and then run your commands in the ssh session. Instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/connect-your-device/ssh) To determine whether your visual c++ app is compatible with Windows IoT, you should run the iot core porting tool which is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/learn-about-hardware/iotcoreportingtool)